# Maven issue with JAVA_HOME

Tags: shell, maven, unix, bash, java-home

Here's what I have in my `.bash_profile`,

```
> export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
> export M2_HOME=/Users/mymac/Documents/apache-maven-3.0.5 export
> PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME
```

`$ echo $PATH` return:

```
> /usr/local/bin: /usr/bin: /bin: /usr/sbin: /sbin:
> /Users/mymac/Documents/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I run `mvn -version`, It says `JAVA_HOME` is not defined correctly.

> We cannot execute
>   Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

The odd thing is that the path that maven returns does not start with a `/` but directly starts with `Library` which is probably is the issue here.

Any suggestions ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Here's some more information. 
If do $ cd / and then $mvn -version, it works. but just mvn from any folder. It doesn't work. What is the reason ?

Comment: First remove `M2_HOME` just add the path to the bin (`PATH=$PATH:/Users/mymac/Documents/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin`) folder to your `PATH` variable. Furthermore set the `JAVA_HOME` to `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk` .

Comment: No luck with your changes above.

Comment: Have you sourced the `.bash..` ..furthermore what is the output resulting and what command have you used ?

Comment: source ~/.bash_profile does not give any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ya well, it was my mistake to have two different profiles one .bash_profile and the other .mavenrc in my home directory. Maven was confused as to where to take the java path from. I removed the .mavenrc and worked fine.

Note:

> export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
>   export M2_HOME=/Users/mymac/Documents/apache-maven-3.0.5 export
>   PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME

Still works.